# Need to know how to Shortcut Groebner Basis by hand

Tags: polynomials, ideals, abelian-varieties, groebner-basis

I have an exam in a few days which includes computing Groebner Basis.

Whilst I have no trouble using Buchberger's algorithm, I am getting confused at smaller 5 mark questions which seemingly skip the algorithm and find the answer quickly.

Here are some examples:

**1)**
Find generating set I ∩ J where $$I = < x^2y + xyz + 1,xy^2 >$$
and $$ J= < x^2 + y^2 +1 > $$

Introducing t by finding $$ N =tI + (1-t)J $$ I compute I ∩ J to be:
$$ < tx^2y+txyz+t, txy^2, -tx^2-ty^2+x^2+y^2+t-1 > $$

which is just horrible!

I know from Maple I should be able to reduce this too $$< x^2+y^2-1, t >$$ but I am unsure how. I know how to continue the question from this point.

**2)** Consider the graph K with vertices VK := {v1, v2, v3} and edges EK := {e12, e13, e23}.
Compute a Gr¨obner basis for IK using the lexicographic order with x1 > x2 > x3. Are the
vertices of K three-colourable?

Again, I know how and can show that they will be three color-able if the reduced gb is not [1]. I use the verticies and edges to find:

$$< x1^2+x1x2+x2^2, x1^2+x1x3+x3^2, x2^2+x2x3+x3^2, x1^3-1, x2^3-1, x3^3-1 >$$

From hours of staring at this equation, I can reduce it to:

$$< x1^2+x1x2+x2^2, x1^2+x1x3+x3^2, x2^2+x2x3+x3^2, x3^3-1 >$$

I am now stuck how to go further.

Any help would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that $I\cap J = N\cap K[x,y]$ is the first elimination ideal of $N$ in $K[t,x,y]$.
By the elimination theorem, using an elimination ordering for $t$ such as the lexicographic ordering with $t>x>y$, compute a Gröbner basis $G$ of $N$.
Then $G' = G\cap K[x,y]$ is Gröbner basis of the first elimination ideal $I\cap J$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am reading the book Ideals, Verities and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'shea. Am i right in thinking the Elimination theory is applied after the Groebner basis is found? We are struggling to find the basis without a large amount of calculations and working using Buchberger's algorithm which doesn't seem correct as there is only 5 marks available for the question.

Comment: Right. The calculation can become rather tedious, since Buchberger's algorithm requires calculating remainders of S-polynomials.

Comment: I have a note here that for **2**, the lecturer jumps from $$<x1x2-x1x3-x2x3-2x^2,x1^2+x1x3+x3^3,x2^2+x2x3+x3^3,x3^3−1>$$

Comment: To $$ < x3^3-1, x2^2+x2x3+x3^2,x1+x2+x3 > $$ in a single step, we do not understand who this happens